# Django primery key error?

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have views like this:

```
def Student_list(request):

    s = Student.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'test_m/test.html', {'s':s})


def Student_info(request, pk):

    C_Details = Student_details.objects.filter(student__pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'test_m/S_info.html', {'C_Details': C_Details})
```

and Models.py like this:

```
models.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models



class Student(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Student_details(models.Model):

    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.CharField(default= 'No Data',max_length=254)
    per = models.CharField(default= 'No Data', max_length=254)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.per
```

My problem is that everything was running fine but In my model I have added several  objects (Ex Student.objects.create(name='John')), and deleted time by time. now what happens I have only one Object in my model. but when its returning  primary key to the template to render the urls:

```
   url(r'^test_m/(?P<pk>\d)/$', views.Student_info, name='Student_info'),

  <td><a href="{% url 'Student_info' pk=s.pk %}"> </a></td> <br>
    </tr>
```

Its should shows primary key as 1 but its showing primary key as 13 and hence its not able to render the urls.

And if I add another object into student it shows 14 and so on so basically its adding every new entry into a base value of 12.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the objects wont reallocate the deleted primary key to an already existing object.

For example if you delete the object with pk=1, the object with pk=2 won't be changed to 1. And if you add a new object, pk of it will be 3 since it is a auto-increment counter

That is the way the database systems are designed.This in no way hinder the working of the django application. And if it bothers you so much you can reset the the auto-increment counter manually keeping the data as it is.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```